# Admin user Partial Catalog

Tags: magento-enterprise, products-management, ce-1.8.1.0, user-roles

Does Magento (EE or CE) have a way of partially restricting catalog access for maintenance? For example, having a user who can only manage products that they personally add OR products in particular categories?

I have a situation in mind where a user might be really effective at managing a particular brand or product genre but I wouldn't want to give full access with all the pricing details for 100% of the store.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible out of the box.
The only restriction you can add on CE for the products is. "Allow it or don't".

For EE you can have an additional restriction for the store views. So you can allow an admin to manage products only for specific store views. But that's it.

Comment: Marius, we're using EE 1.13.1. If a user has access to a store view. How would that work so the products showed up on the main store? Would writing a script to add all store 2 items to the main store work?

Comment: The script would have to do more than change the products store visibilIty right?  Would there be issues wrY categories and sharing attribute sets

Comment: I honestly have no idea on how to proceed. I haven't used EE in a while

Answer (score 0):

Magento access list system doesn't allow to assign content specific permission. Howevere, there's number of extension that provide workaround of for such limitation. I recommend searching for "Magento Advanced Admin Permissions".

For example this extension should do the trick:

http://amasty.com/magento-advanced-permissions.html

PS. I haven't used it myself, so no guarantees here that it works like advertised.